# Calling FFMPEG's av_frame_free from managed vc++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I am trying to compile the following code fragment in vc++ 2010 (using /cli flag):

```
 AVFrame * m_Decoded = av_frame_alloc();
 av_frame_free(&m_Decoded);
```

However, the second line throws an error:

error C2664: 'av_frame_free' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::interior_ptr' to 'AVFrame **'

Any idea how to bypass this problem?

Thanks!

Ofer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try pin_ptr?

```
pin_ptr<AVFrame*> ptr = &m_Decoded;
av_frame_free( ptr );
```

Comment: Yes I did and it worked! However, at first I tried pin_ptr<AVFrame**> ptr = &m_Decoded; which seems more intuitive, but that didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: pin_ptr<type> is a pointer to a type* - see how the stars match.